# How to override all colors in bootstrap 4?

Tags: sass, bootstrap-4

I took time learning how to theme bootstrap using SASS. Steps were as follows:

- In my project directory at command line ran `npm install bootstrap --save`
- Then I wrote to *main.scss* file with

```
$theme-colors: (
  "primary": #9b2335,
  "secondary": #696969,
  "success": #d9596c,
  "info": #d02f47,
  "warning": #e38291,
  "danger":#de6e7e,
  "light": #d9d9d9,
  "dark": #333333
);

@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

- At command line ran `sass main.scss main.css`

And with that I would expect ALL theme colors to be overwritten. Please note, all of my custom `$theme-color` variables are a hue in either the red or gray family. Nothing about those color values is blue. However, the border around my navbar toggle button is blue when focused (see pic). Why did it not change to one of my custom theme colors? I did look through *_variables.scss* but nothing obvious jumped out at me.

The html for my page was copied from the bootstrap album example, but the important part I think is this:

```
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarHeader" aria-controls="navbarHeader" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
```

What Sass am I missing here to override ALL colors?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

that's the default bootstrap focus color from ("_reboot.scss"):

```
button:focus {
  outline: 1px dotted;
  outline: 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;
}
```

if you want to set a color from your theme you have to override it. f.e.:

```
button:focus {
  outline: 5px auto map-get($theme-colors, "primary");
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved my issue. Is there a way to override everything where the `:focus` selector comes into play? I was under the impression my `$theme-colors` would have trickled down to cover all this stuff like the `:focus`, `:hover` etc. But guess that's not how it works.

Comment: My guess is that they are using the default behaviour of the browser for the focus. One could argue that removing it is a wrong move in term of accessibility.